# How to upgrade g++ on mac?

Tags: c++

I tried:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> A = {1,2,3,4,5};

    cout << A[1];

    return 0;
}
```

**stl.cpp:8:14: error: non-aggregate type 'vector' cannot be initialized
      with an initializer list**

Now, I realize I need to upgrade g++ on my mac. I need help to do that, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you choose the correct c++ version when compiling that file? Which gcc version is installed, and how do you use g++ to compile the file?

Comment: I do :- ```g++ -o <fileIwant> <myfilename.cpp>```
<br>
and when I do ```g++ --version``` in terminal, the result is:-
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Comment: `g++` points to Clang nowadays. Clang still uses `-std=c++03` for a default. Use `clang++ -std=c++11 ...` as part of your command line. If you still want to upgrade GCC, then install MacPorts and then install a compiler like `g++-mp-7` or `g++-mp-8`.

Comment: Usually instead of upgrading just g++, you upgrade to the latest Xcode, and get a newer version of g++ (which is actually clang++ these days) as part of that install.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I do not have xcode on my mac. Is it necessary to have xcode?

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, but it's highly recommended -- Xcode is the usual development toolset for working under MacOS/X, so if you use it, most things will "just work", whereas if you go with a less-universally-used solution you'll probably end up having to figure out a number of issues on your own.  (Once you have Xcode installed and told it to "install command line tools", it works pretty much the same as any Unix build environment; in particular you don't have to use the Xcode IDE if you don't want to)

Comment: Xcode is divided into two parts the command line tools (tool chain) that is already installed on your setup, and the IDE providing a UI, profiling, ... on top of the tool chain. So installing the IDE is not required if only want to use the command line compiler. Just add the c++ version you want to use as command line option.

Comment: @t.niese how do i do that?

Comment: As written in an earlier comment use the compiler options `-std=c++11` (for c++11).